# Trouble installing Windows Admin Center 1809 on Server 1803 via command line error 1603

Tags: windows, windows-server-core

I am attempting to install Windows Admin Center 1809 on Server 1803.
I ran under administrator context:

> msiexec /I windowsAdminCenter1809.msi /qn /L*v log.txt SSL_CERTIFICATE_OPTION=generate

The error recorded in the log file was:

```
C:\Windows\Installer\MSI814D.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Setup.CustomActions!Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Setup.CustomActions.CustomAction.GenerateSslCertificate
Exception: 
System.ArgumentException
Custom action data improperly initialized
Parameter name: session 
at Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Setup.CustomActions.CustomAction.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<GenerateSslCertificate>b__0()
at Microsoft.ManagementExperience.Setup.CustomActions.CustomAction.RunInstallerAction(Session session, Func`1 action)
MSI (s) (1C!B8) [16:24:06:470]: Product: Windows Admin Center -- 1: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException Custom action data improperly initialized
Parameter name: session 

1: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException Custom action data improperly initialized
Parameter name: session 
CustomAction GenerateSslCertificate returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

I then ran the msi interactive, selecting the same SSL generation and it worked.  Any clues what I did wrong?

Comment: interactive it run under your username, the install line was executed how? in elevated cmd in example?

Comment: I ran as administrator on the server core cmd shell.